# Отображение файлов в папке

Tags: c#, wpf

Вывожу в окне содержание папки

```
dirs = Directory.GetFiles(mw.paths[1]);

            foreach (string dir in dirs)
            {
               //код
            }
```

Список файлов выводится, но он автоматически сортируется по алфавиту, и если изменить имя файла или удалить его, то в окне ничего не поменяется, пока я не закрою окно и не открою снова
Подскажите, как лучше сделать отображение файлов в папке?

Comment: `но он автоматически сортируется по алфавиту` и что вы хотите вместо этого?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Мне не пришлось использовать [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)
Я создал новый класс, который отвечал за удаление и изменение имени файла, и в момент изменения файла вызывал метод класса

Comment: Ага, а если файл удалит другой процесс? Не, правильно делать через FileSystemWatcher.

Comment: @VladD, это уже зависит от пользователя

Comment: Это да. Но ведь проводник убирает файл из списка даже если вы удаляете его программой? Так что автообновление списка файлов — это ожидаемая пользователем фича.

Comment: @VladD, суть в том, что у пользователя нет доступа к директории с теми файлами, разве что через программу

Comment: Ну, на мой вкус это очень хрупкое условие. А если пользователь запустит два экземпляра программы?

Comment: @VladD, если запустить окно, в котором показывается список 2 раза, к примеру. Если в первом окне удалить один файл, то во втором окне изменения покажутся, если провести какое-либо редактирование любого иного файла
В любом случае, моя программа не предназначается для столь изощренного использования

Answer (score 5):

Всё уже готово: [FileSystemWatcher](https://msdn.microsoft.com/ru-ru/library/system.io.filesystemwatcher(v=vs.110).aspx)

Можно подписаться на событие `Renamed` и отображать актуальные данные:

```
watcher.Renamed += new RenamedEventHandler(OnRenamed);

private static void OnRenamed(object source, RenamedEventArgs e)
{
    // тут пишите что делать.
    Console.WriteLine("File: {0} renamed to {1}", e.OldFullPath, e.FullPath);
}
```

Comment: А можно наглядный пример? Я попробовал пример скопировать, чисто чтобы проверить, но у меня ничего не выводит

Comment: @andrew, на MSDN вам не достаточно??! `watcher.Created += new FileSystemEventHandler(OnChanged);`